# Why doesn't the html 5 attribute not respect a value of false?

Tags: html, reactjs

In the [description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) from Mozilla it states that the "hidden" attribute on an element is a boolean global attribute.  When I use something like:

```
<div hidden="false">Test</div>
```

the element remains hidden.  It appears that the existence of that attribute regardless of value, hides the content.  I would assume that this would work the same as the disabled attribute.

I am asking this question because I am using BootStrap 4 Beta and ReactJs and I want to conditionally show or hide an element using the attribute without having to resort to using jQuery.

Comment: Giving an attribute any kind of value makes the attribute true. `<div hidden>`, `<div hidden="abc">` and `<div hidden="true">` are the same thing.

Comment: I can set a <button disabled="false"> and it will not be disabled.  It seems like your comment might be incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set a value you actually flag it as true (can't find the reference for it but i read about it somewhere).
With react you do have other options of course:

1. Use a `css` class with `display:none` for example.
2. Conditionally render the element, it wont be hidden but will be absent.

**EDIT**
Found the [reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/semantics.html#boolean) :)

> A number of attributes in HTML5 are boolean attributes. The presence
>   of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and
>   the absence of the attribute represents the false value.

**A number of attributes...**

Comment: I added a comment above regarding the disabled attribute that makes me question that.  I will have to check for a reference.

Comment: yeah, "A number of attributes" would be a key point here. i guess i forgot to mention this part :)